# How can I use ethers.js to get streaming events via sockets instead of polling?

Tags: ethers.js, events, rpc

I try to use ethers.js events, but they seem to be polling constantly and eventually the RPC provider sends HTTP code 429: Too Many Requests.

I understand that I can use non-standard APIs of providers, to set up webhooks. (Actually, I don't know of any providers that let me set up webhooks programmatically, except Moralis. Does anyone know any others? Please let me know in a comment, if you do.)

But is there some sort of "streaming websocket" standard that ethers.js could use with a provider, to receive events when they arrive?

Also as a related part of the question: if I give the client a token with which to issue transactions, can't the client use up my entire API quota with the RPC provider with unlimited transactions? And similarly with this websocket thing. So maybe I have to use webhooks if I want to protect my API credits?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/providers/#WebSocketProvider

check websocket  provider out, doesn't poll i beleive, haven't really used it to the point of being cork sure

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).